# How to remove padding from action bar logo?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've managed to set a logo for action bar using these lines of code:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); //optional
```

but there is always some sort of padding at the right of the logo. Is there a way to eliminate it?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setContentInsetsAbsolute(int leftInset, int rightInset)` on your toolbar

The values are in `dp` by default it's set at `16dp`

Answer (score 0):

My typical solution when I want to go above and beyond what the ActionBar is designed for is to hide the ActionBar completely using

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

and instead implement a relative layout within the activity's layout file that follows the guidelines of an ActionBar as outlined by google [HERE](https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar)

This provides the flexibility to alter the appearance to whatever degree you'd like while maintaining the graphical appearance of Material Design.